# Sorting array by keys that include logical operators

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, php-7.1

Curious if this has been solved before as my google-fu can't seem to find this one. I have an array like this:

```
[
    "<=4/2" => 233
    "16/8" => 73
    ">16/8" => 122
    "8/4" => 21
]
```

I need to sort this like so, in human readable ascending order:

```
[
    "<=4/2" => 233
    "8/4" => 21
    "16/8" => 73
    ">16/8" => 122
]
```

I know I can code to strip the logical operators, compare the keys, then compare where the logical operators should fall, sort the array by those keys, etc.

But is there a function that I can just use that exists? It seems like I may not be the first person to do this.

PHP 7.1.x

Laravel framework

Comment: Of course you are the first person to do this, write your code, and come here if you have any problem.

Comment: Are these dates that you're trying to order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*there is no magical function that will sort by ignoring those operators.*

since you already use Laravel, you can convert array to collection and use `sortBy` method to sort array with custom algorithm.

```
$collection = collect([
    '<=4/2' => 233,
    '16/8' => 73,
    '>16/8' => 122,
    '8/4' => 21,
]);
$sorted = $collection->sortBy(function ($value, $key) {
    return preg_replace('/\D/', '', $key);
});
```

or if you wanna use plain PHP, you can use `uksort`

```
$array = [
    '<=4/2' => 233,
    '16/8' => 73,
    '>16/8' => 122,
    '8/4' => 21,
];

uksort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return preg_replace('/\D/', '', $a) > preg_replace('/\D/', '', $b);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that those keys are strings that represent dates in d/M format, you could do it like this:

```
function keyOrder($key) {
    if ($key[0] === "<") return -1;
    if ($key[0] === ">") return 10000;
    list($day, $month) = explode("/", $key);
    return $month*100+$day;
}

uksort($data, function($a, $b) { return keyOrder($a) - keyOrder($b); } );
```